# Grails - localhost:8080 refused to connect

Tags: grails

I am trying to run my first Grails app and I am getting a error when I try to go to localhost:8080. It just refuses to connect.

I followed Dan Vega's instructions in his video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlMyRGIJNa0 carefully but I cannot get my app to run.

I have tried to change the host but couldn't get to the right place to do so. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change you server port. You need to add in `application.yml` as follow to run

```
server:
    port: 8181
```

Comment: I have tried that. But now when I type in 'grails run-app' it starts downloading a lot of files. Is this normal? It went on downloading for at least 5 minutes before I stopped it. Usually it shouldn't take that long to download the right files to run an app?

Comment: If it is your first time it could take a while to resolve all the dependencies you need. just let it run. It should only happen once and be cached.